# Reclass for vector data in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, vector, classification

I've got a vector dataset (in fact, OS MasterMap data) and I want to set the value of a certain field based on the value of another field. For example:

```
Field1        Field2
Building      20
Grass         50
Water         19
```

In the above, I want to set the value of Field2 based on the value in Field1, that is - all records that have Building in Field1 should have Field2 set to the value of 20.

I know I can do this by doing Select by Attribute and then using the Field Calculator to give the selected records a value, but doing this loads of times is going to get very boring.

Is there a way to give ArcGIS Desktop a sort of table of values like you do in the Raster Reclass tool, and get it to do it automatically?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yes**.  The following technique is general and works in all relational databases and (therefore) in many GISes.

**Create a lookup table describing the reclassification**: it will look exactly like the table in the question.  **Joining** the lookup table to your attribute table on [Field1] completes the job.

**This solution is fully automatic**: any update to the attribute table or the lookup table will be immediately reflected in the join.

If you need to make the result permanent (*e.g.,* for use in other software), use the Field Calculator simply to copy the value of [Field2] into a new field created for that purpose.  This, of course, is not automatic at all and would have to be repeated whenever a value of [Field1] is changed, or [Field2] is updated in the lookup table, or records are added to the attribute table.

BTW, this used to be a great way to reclassify integer (categorical) grids in Spatial Analyst, but in recent versions, joins to grid tables do not seem to work correctly.  Anyone with a positive experience in this regard please correct me (maybe the situation has improved at version 10.0?).

Answer (score 5):

The online help for  [Arcmap 10](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Calculate_Field_examples/00170000004s000000/) shows some field calculation examples using Python code blocks, to reclass data.  If you didn't have to many cases, the example could provide some guidance.  See the section called *Calculate fields using logic with Python* and
*Classify based on field values* near the middle of the link.